# organizer sync all the apps from all itune accounts that are signedIn in the Xcode and make it soo slow

Tags: ios, xcode

I have upload many app on iTunes store on daily bases on different accounts
whenever I archive a new app from xCode and organizer starts it archive the app with no issue but after that it start sync all the apps from all accounts that are signedIn in the xCode even some have not been uploaded by me on iTunes store.
I have also tried to delete all archives from xCode
it makes my Xcode too slow and some time it take too much time to make xCode responsive.
and when the sync completes it shows all the app on the left side of the organizer and then let me start uploading on the itune store

Comment: no one know this issue i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple solution
just go to the
- Xcode's preferences
- Account Tab
- Remove all accounts from it (just leave a temporary account just for testing if you want)
-and upload Apps using Application Loader(Xcode, open developer tool, application Loader)
This is due to all account fetching all app information from all account signedIN in your Xcode
After this Xcode will work like charm